# How to return string from a Class?

Tags: c#

I'm New to c# and I've been playing around with it and got stuck at returning something useful from a method. Any help will be great.

I Have this right now:

in `Form1.cs`:

```
Animal NewAnimal = new Animal("Jack", "Ramp");
```

In `Animal.cs`:

```
public Animal(string Fname, string Lname)
        {
            if (Fname == "Jack" | Lname == "Ramp")
            {
                string FullName;
                FullName = Fname + " " + Lname;
                //return FullName; <--- This is what i tried but didn't work--->
            }
        }
        //return FullName; <--- And Also tried this it didn't work --->
```

Maybe from the ones I tried I'm doing something wrong? How would I return the FullName to Form1.cs and display it in a label?

Comment: You can't return a value in the constructor.  Make a property for fullname and get that from your class.

Comment: So why are you using a `single bar` for the If statement? You know the difference between `conditional or` and `bitwise or`, right?

Comment: @gunr2171 I believe the | operator evaluate both sides of the statement instead of short circuiting with the || operator.  This should work.

Comment: @Harrison, I'm really sure you are thinking of the wrong thing. Who cares if this "short circuts"? Either A or B or both need to match, so it will find the first one that works and not do the rest. This is faster anyways. And I'm really sure that a bitwise is flat out wrong here.

Comment: @gunr2171: according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx it's not wrong and can be used as bitwise or logical OR.  "For bool operands, | computes the logical OR of its operands; that is, the result is false if and only if both its operands are false".  Although I agree that the || operator is better/faster in this and most circumstances

Comment: @gunr2171 You're both right. `|` will work with this comparison because the statement simplifies `Fname == "Jack | Lname == "Ramp"` --> `bool | bool`, and will evaluate both boolean values. `||` will short-circuit and for this kind of comparison, will always be just fine, and is the better choice. `|` is only a bitwise operation for integral types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your shoes, I would review the basics of specifying a type in C#.

A type is a user-defined (that's you being the *user*) collection of fields, properties, methods, and a few other constructs that define data and behavior.

If your particular case, you need to consider the behaviors you're implementing.

- Feeding a string to a new `Animal`
- Getting that string from an `Animal`

Consider the following code:

```
public class Animal { 
  public string FullName { get; }

  public Animal(string firstName, string lastName) { 
    this.FullName = firstName + " " + lastName; 
  }
}
```

You can then retrieve the name of an `Animal` you instantiate.

```
var animal = new Animal("Bob", "Smith"); 
// ... later
if (animal.FullName.Equals("Jack Ramp", StringComparison.CurrentCulture)); 
textBox.Text = animal.FullName;
```

If this gets you a little lost, I'd recommend reviewing (and actually working through the contained examples) in the
[Microsoft Types Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173104.aspx). There is quite a bit of information in this article, but it's all important information on C#'s type system.

Answer (score 5):

You want something like this:

```
public class Animal
{
    public Animal(string fName, string lName)
    {
        this.FName = fName;
        this.LName = lName;
    }
    public string FName {get;set;}
    public string LName {get;set;}
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        { 
            return String.Format("{0} {1}", FName,LName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to return a value from the constructor ...

Define a method instead.

```
public string FullName(string Fname, string Lname)
{
if (Fname == "Jack" || Lname == "Ramp")
   {

                return Fname + " " + Lname;

    }

return "";

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The method that you have is called a `Constructor`. It is called when you want to create a new instance of an object. Although it has no return type in the definition, it "returns" a new instance of your object (though you can't really control that).

What you are expecting is to have another public method or property that will return a value.

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Fullname {get; set;}

    public Animal(string Fname, string Lname)
    {
        if (Fname == "Jack" || Lname == "Ramp")
        {
            FullName = Fname + " " + Lname;
        }
}
```

Then use the following:

```
Animal NewAnimal = new Animal("Jack", "Ramp");
var firstName = NewAnimal.FullName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yaur's answer will work but to get closer to what you seem to be asking for I would do it (note: this is a modification of Yaur's code)

```
public class Animal
{
    public Animal(string fName, string lName)
    {
        this.FName = fName;
        this.LName = lName;
    }
    public string FName {get;set;}
    public string LName {get;set;}
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} {1}", FName,LName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not return something from a constructor. you can declare a property or a public field, like this

```
class Animal {

public:
   string FullName;
    .....
}
```

then you can access `FullName` by `NewAnimal.FullName`.